# Adding a library in R console

Tags: c, r

I would like to add an external library (that I do have az a Zip file).

Generally, how to deal with external packages on R console?

Comment: `install.packages("filepath.zip", repos = NULL)`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik you could add this as an answer, or I'll do it ;)

Comment: You do it, @PaulHiemstra.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Roman suggested:

```
install.packages("filepath.zip", repos = NULL)
```